# Android: how to emulate webcam as emulator front camera

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wanted to use the webcam of my pc as the front camera of the android emulator i'm currently using, so as to simulate services like skype.

I'm using android sdk ver 21.

Comment: hey,what you have tired?

Comment: i am a very basic user, i tried using the webcam0 and emulated options available while creating a new avd (note: they're only available in rev. 20+ of android sdk). none of them worked, the camera process crashes on starting it from within the avd, with the webcam connected and powered on.